# Receiving getExecuting FilePath error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tsc

I am using WebStorm for a node.js application developed using transpiled TypeScript. Whenever I run the tsconfig.json by selecting "compile all" from the TypeScript tab, I get the following error:

> Error:Initialization error (typescript). Cannot read property 'getExecutingFilePath' of undefined.

However, if I execute one file at a time I receive "Service is not started".

Here is the tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "ES6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
  "lib": ["ES6"],
  "sourceMap": true,
  "inlineSources": true,
  "pretty": true,
  "outDir": "dist",
  "rootDir": "src",
  "noLib": false,
  "declaration": true
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"include": [
  "src/**/*"
],
"exclude": [
  "node_modules"
]
}
```

Also, I notice that I do not see the TypeScript words at the bottom right of the screen:

[image]

I noticed that if I do a `tsc --version` from the console, I am getting Version 2.0.2, whereas, if I `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript`, I am getting 2.6.2 for WebStorm. If I run `tsc` from the command line it seems to work but not from within WebStorm. What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Looks like a config issue... Screenshot the `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript` screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I noticed that if I do a tsc --version from the console, I am getting
>   Version 2.0.2, whereas, if I Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks ->
>   TypeScript, I am getting 2.6.2 for WebStorm

You have TypeScript 2.0.2 installed globally, and 2.6.2 is your local project version. By default, WebStorm uses TypeScript installed in project node_modules.

Most probably, your WebStorm version doesn't support TypeScript 2.6.x (this release includes breaking API changes, so tsserver integration might stop working). Please change TypeScript version to **Bundled** in **Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript** - does it help?

Comment: That seemed to fix it.  Though, now I am getting alot of compile errors out of my "node_modules/@types" folder even though I have node_modules excluded in my tsconfig.json file.

Comment: `@types` are implicitly included in the compilation - this is the expected behavior. To exclude them, add `"types": []` to your `tsconfig.json`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html: `By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.`

Comment: In my phpstorm I have an option to automatically detect typescript version. Also I have an option to choose a custom version. But from you answer those options are not tend to work. So why phpstorm added them? Is it that I can use only bundled version and not others?